# How to run old Windows (Win 95, x86) application on Windows 7 (x64)

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

I tried to install application that worked on win 95 and windows xp and got error on windows 7 (x64):

The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

So settings did not help me.

[image]

Could anyone explain: can I run so application on Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: It completely depends on the application.  Depending on the application, it may not be possible to get it to work at all.  You may have to use XP mode (a Windows XP virtual machine).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like this might be a 16-bit application.  While 16-bit applications are supported on 32-bit XP, they are not supported on 64-bit systems:

[64-bit versions of Windows do not support 16-bit components, 16-bit processes, or 16-bit applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896458)

Comment: +1 for the right answer.  [That's exactly what that message indicates.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb756962.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Basically on you will probably not be able to run your application on native Win 7, and as you have found that the compatibility are not totally useful.

You can try: (1) XP mode which can be freely obtained for running XP applications under Win 7, also (2) Load up an XP host on Oracle Virtual Box and then try your application finally there is (3) loading up an XP host on VMWare Workstation (cost $$) and try your application.  No guarantees on any of these because it depends a lot on the application construction itself.

Comment: My application (game) requires DirectX to be installed. Game shipped with DX 2.0. My Win 7 has 6.0. By the way I have installed my game on VMWare machine (Vista), but I cannot install old directX on virtual machine. Weird situation.

Comment: Win7 have DirectX **11**, which is backward compatible with DirectX 9, which have WinXP, which can play your game. BTW, only Win95 OSR2 had DirectX 2.0a from 5 June 1996. Install WinXP in VM and nothing more